# Specific example of a space that is separable but not second countable.

Tags: general-topology

> A toplogical space $X$ is said to be second countable
>   if there exists a countable basis for the topology.
>
> $X$ is separable if there exist a countable dense subset.
>   Show that a second countable space always is separable.
>
> Give an example of a space that is separable but not 
>   second countable

The first part was easy and i managed to solve it on my own

Assume that $X$ is second countable and let $B_1, B_2, B_3...$
be a countable basis. Construct the set $A$ by taking one
element $x_n$ out of every $B_n$. Then $A$ becomes dense because
every open set $U$ contain a $B_n$ which in turn contain the
element $x_n$ in $A$.

---

Again, like in the question i posted yesterday, i had trouble to come up with an example but our
professor gave an example during the last lecture but
i dont fully understand it:

"For an example of a separable but not second countable
space let $X$ be the real line provided with the cofinite
topology, i.e. where a set is open if its either empty
or if its complement is finite.

Then every infinite set is dense and hence $X$ is separable.

But for an arbitrary countable family of open sets
$U_1, U_2...$ write $U_i = X$\ $A_i$, where $A_i$ is finite,
there is an element $x \in X$\ $(\cup_i Ai)$, because $A_i$ is countable, 
such that the open set $X$\ $\{x\}$ is then not able
to contain any $U_i$. Consequently $X$ is not second countable."

We asked him to explain it in more detail but his english is poor
and nobody understood anything...:)

---

> **Def:** A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is dense in $X$ if for any point $x$ in $X$, any neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point from $A$.

$1.$ "Then every infinite set is dense"

Take $A$ to be one of these infinite sets. If $x \in A \subset X$ then it trivially fulfills the definition. But if we take a $x \not\in A$ why is it not possible to find a neighborhood in these finite sets that does not contain an element in $A$?

edit: its obvious if it is only open neighborhoods, open sets in the topology, but that is not specified in the definition.

$2.$ I am not fully understanding this either

"But for an arbitrary countable family of open sets
$U_1, U_2...$ write $U_i = X$\ $A_i$, where $A_i$ is finite,
there is an element $x \in X$\ $(\cup_i Ai)$, because $A_i$ is countable, 
such that the open set $X$\ $\{x\}$ is then not able
to contain any $U_i$. Consequently $X$ is not second countable."

Is it possible to express this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology on $\Bbb R$. The members of $\tau$ (i.e., the open sets in this space) are $\varnothing$, the empty set, and all subsets of $\Bbb R$ of the form $\Bbb R\setminus F$, where $F$ is any finite subset of $\Bbb R$.

Now let $A$ be any infinite subset of $\Bbb R$, and let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus A$. Suppose that $x\in U\in\tau$, i.e., that $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$. Then by definition there is some finite set $F\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $U=\Bbb R\setminus F$. That is, there are only finitely many real numbers — the members of $F$ — that are *not* in $U$. The set $A$ is infinite, so there must be some $a\in A\setminus F$. This real number $a$ is not in $F$, so it *is* in $U$. Thus, $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$. $U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $x$, so we’ve shown that *every* open nbhd of $x$ contains some element of $A$, and therefore $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. As you’ve already pointed out, $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, so we’ve now shown that every real number is in $\operatorname{cl}A$: $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb R$, and hence $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

This is true for every infinite subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$. In particular, it’s true for the countably infinite set $\Bbb N$: $\Bbb N$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ in this topology, and since $\Bbb N$ is countable, $\langle\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ is a separable space.

Now we need to show that the topology $\tau$ has no countable base. Suppose that $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable family of open sets in this space; we’ll show that $\mathscr{B}$ is not a base for $\tau$ by finding a $U\in\tau$ that is not the union of members of $\mathscr{B}$.

We can assume that the members of $\mathscr{B}$ are all non-empty: there’s never any need to include the empty set in a base for a topology. Thus, by the definition of the topology $\tau$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a finite $F_n\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $B_n=\Bbb R\setminus F_n$. Let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$; $A$ is the union of countably many finite sets, so $A$ is countable. $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so there is some $x\in\Bbb R\setminus A$. Let $U=\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$; the set $\{x\}$ is finite, so by definition $U\in\tau$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary; then $x\notin A\supseteq F_n$, so $x\notin F_n$, and therefore $x\in B_n$. But this means that $x\in B_n\setminus U$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and hence that $B_n\nsubseteq U$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Clearly this implies that $U$ is not the union of members of $\mathscr{B}$, which therefore cannot be a base for $\tau$. And since we’ve done this far an arbitrary countable subset $\mathscr{B}$ of $\tau$, we’ve shown that $\tau$ has no countable base and hence that $\langle\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ is not second countable.

Comment: I call your cofinite topology, and raise you with separability by a dense point.

Comment: @Asaf: I wonder what the simplest Hausdorff example is. If we want a nice example we have Mrówka’s $\Psi$, and if we want a really nice example we have $\beta\omega$, but those are both a bit complicated for a beginner.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that the less $T_i$ the space, the easier the example becomes.

Comment: I'd vote for the Sorgenfrey line. Separable is easy, not second countable not too hard. And it's hereditarily normal.

Comment: @Henno: And it’s an example commonly found in elementary courses. Yes, that’s a good choice.

Comment: Toplogogy is hard. :) But really fun at the same time. I probably need to read your answer a couple of more times to fully understand it. But it definitely was a good answer, thanks!

Comment: I will accept your answer either way but i think you missed one thing in my question nr 1.. "its obvious if it is only open neighborhoods but that is not specified in the definition." In my definition, which is in my question, of dense sets that is. What happens if its a closed neighborhood of x? How do you have to change your answer then? Or is my definition not complete, i.e. i mean that you should always assume that the neighborhood is open?

Comment: @JKnecht: You're right: I did miss that. It doesn't matter whether you consider just open nbhds or all nbhds, since every nbhd of $x$ contains an open nbhd of $x$, and it must intersect $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Take your favorite uncountable set $X$ and fix $x\in X$. Now consider the following topology: $$\{U\subseteq X\mid \varnothing\neq U\leftrightarrow x\in U\}$$

Namely, every non-empty open set contains $x$, and vice versa. This is not a second-countable topology, since a second-countable topology implies being Lindelöf, but $\{\{x,y\}\mid y\in X\}$ is an open cover without a countable subcover.

But $\{x\}$ is dense, since it meets every non-empty open set. So this topology is separable.

Comment: Thanks to you too! It is always helpful to look a multiple examples.